# Sending Key Strokes with C# in Win10 outside of app

Tags: c#, windows-10, sendkeys

I am trying to send a simple `"CTRL+C"` stroke to another window.

The idea is to grab text from `IE/FF/Chrome/IE/Excel/Word`.  Anyway, I have tried to use `SendKeys.Send()` and `SendKeys.SendWait()` and InputSimulator's `Keyboard.KeyPress()`.  None of them throw exceptions (Well `SendKeys.Send()`, but that's expected) but none of them actually send anything.

I have tried to just send letter presses and nothing happens.  I will include code snippets to see if maybe I am doing something real dense but I worry its a Win10 isolation thing. Has anyone had luck sending keystrokes outside of their own app in Win10 yet?

Sendkeys:

```
public void DoItDamnYou()
{
    SendKeys.SendWait("C");
    MessageBox.Show("Press SHOULD have happened");
}
```

InputSimulator

```
public void DoItDamnYouNow()
{
    InputSimulator input = new InputSimulator();
    input.Keyboard.KeyPress(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.VK_D);
    MessageBox.Show("Now we are in the wrapper.");
}
```

If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate them.

Thanks

Comment: You're running your app with elevated privileges?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I wasn't and didn't want to reply until I coild check. But running in as admin had not effect. Still will not send keys.

Comment: Confirmed, active window loses focus in Windows 10 when SendKeys.SendWait is called, it is just that no one aknowledges this and takes measures... I think they envision it as a new security feature for Windows 10, one that breaks a lot of functionality tho...

Answer (score 1):

Seems Sendkeys are disabled in Windows 10. In Windows 8.1 , Diasbling UAC in Registry I can use SendKeys to Windows Calculator as usual. In Windows 10, disabling the UAC in Restry the Calculator will not launch at all. Enabling the UAC the Calculator launches, but is not accepting any Sendkeys Command, but is accepting the Ctrl+V and Ctrl+C (read and copy to Clipboard) issued from directly from Keyboard.