# c# windows 10 capturing and sending keys

Tags: c#

I have a simple app coded with c# which captures pressed keys out of the form and also sends keys also outside the form. The app works well with windows7.

But when I tested it on windows 10 it couldn't capture or send keys if the app wasn't active (outside the form).

Comment: Why not share some code?

Comment: @PatrickHofman All the code is about KeyHandler for capturing pressed keys and SendKeys.SendWait for sending keys

Comment: @FirasSy you need to show us

Comment: Seems like another SO post has reported a similar problem in Windows 10: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846863/sending-key-strokes-with-c-sharp-in-win10-outside-of-app

Comment: @SpecialSauce yes I've checked it.. it's the same problem.. but with no answer..

Comment: @Paul the code is similar to the shared code in the link of Special Sauce's comment.. and it works very well on win7.. the problem only with win10

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41886193/1599699